# Best lightweight linux IRC server for a team

Tags: linux, irc, instant-messaging

I'm looking for suggestions for an extremely lightweight IRC server for linux. It does not need a bunch of features or bloat. It's is for just our internal team (50- people), and small footprint is important.

I've been looking at InspireIRC, but wanted to get other opinions.

And advice you can provide will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not worked with a IRCd in a while, but from my past experience if your running a small capacity IRCd then your not going to be using up alot of system resources where as a large capacity IRCd would use up alot of system resources. My suggestion would be either InspireIRC, UnrealIRCd or UltimateIRCd because they give you the option of what modules to run with the server.

Answer (score 7):

I know its late in the game to get in on this answer, but I have recently been looking at doing this myself, and found these two options as well:

https://github.com/jrosdahl/miniircd

http://ngircd.barton.de/

Both seem quite simple to setup and use and lean by skipping most features that a small/private IRCd wont need...

Comment: ngIRCd can be installed by the `apt` command on Debian 9 Stretch and works very well!